# Serializing a C# object with additional and different element tags

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am creating an API wrapper which gets an API response and converts it to POCO objects.
Right now I have a test that follows this sequence of actions:

- Create object with XML element names and values.
- Serialize this object to XML format.
- Convert the XML tree back to an actual object trough my converter.
- Assert if the values inside my new object are as expected.

I have the following helper class which represents a show object:

```
class TestShow {
 public string id { get; set; }
 public string IMDB_ID { get; set; }
 public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

The serializer:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(show.GetType());
string xml;

using (var writer = new StringWriter()) {
   serializer.Serialize(writer, show);
   xml = writer.ToString();
}
```

However, when I serialize this to XML I get this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<TestShow xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <id>76290</id>
  <IMDB_ID>tt0285331</IMDB_ID>
  <Language>en</Language>
</TestShow>
```

The desired result is this:

```
<Data>
 <Series>
  <id>76290</id>
  <IMDB_ID>tt0285331</IMDB_ID>
  <Language>en</Language>
 </Series>
</Data>
```

This shows two issues:

1. The name of `TestShow` should be changed to `Series`. Is there an easy way to do this, or should I just change my class name?
2. There is an upper collection called `Data`. How would I add this?

Comment: What serialiser are you using?

Comment: @SamLeach: I've added the serializer. It's the standard `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: Use attributes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add Xml attributes to the POCO:

```
class TestShow 
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string IMDB_ID { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("Data")]
class Data 
{
    [XmlElement("Series")]
    public TestShow TestShow { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The `XmlElement` tag throws an error: `Attribute 'XmlElement' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'property, indexer, field, param, return' declarations.` Are you sure it can be placed as a class tag?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: No, it should be moved to adorn the `public TestShow TestShow { get; set; }` line.